# Internet Explorer don't POST

Tags: javascript, post, internet-explorer, abap

I am working on a SAP interface project, in which the standard call is usually the Internet Explorer. I am trying to gather the information processed by HTML within the IE and send it to SAP using the following code:

```
REPORT demo_html_input.

INCLUDE: ZCAS_TEXT_POST_HTML_SRC.

TYPES: typ_html_code TYPE TABLE OF char255 WITH EMPTY KEY,
       typ_source    TYPE TABLE OF string.

CLASS html_start DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS: constructor,
             txt_html RETURNING VALUE(lt_codigo) TYPE string.
  PRIVATE SECTION.


    data: lv_html_code type string.
    METHODS: get_source,
             descomented
             IMPORTING
               lt_source    TYPE typ_source
             EXPORTING
               lv_html_code TYPE string.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS html_start IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD constructor.
    get_source( ).
  endmethod.

  METHOD txt_html.
    lt_codigo = lv_html_code.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD get_source.
    DATA: lt_source TYPE TABLE OF string.

    CALL METHOD cl_reca_rs_services=>get_source
      EXPORTING
        id_objtype = 'PROG'
        id_objname = 'ZCAS_TEXT_POST_HTML_SRC'
      IMPORTING
        et_source  = lt_source.

    descomented( EXPORTING
                        lt_source = lt_source
                       IMPORTING
                         lv_html_code = lv_html_code ).
  ENDMETHOD.


  METHOD descomented.
    DATA: ls_html_code TYPE char255.
    DATA: ls_source TYPE string.

    DATA: lv_len_data TYPE i,
          lv_len_source TYPE i,
          lv_len_total TYPE i,
          lv_str_max  type i,
          lv_string TYPE string.

    LOOP AT lt_source INTO ls_source.
      TRY .
          ls_source = ls_source+1.
        CATCH cx_sy_range_out_of_bounds.
      ENDTRY.


      SHIFT ls_source RIGHT DELETING TRAILING ' '.
      SHIFT ls_source LEFT DELETING LEADING ' '.

      lv_string = ls_source .
      CONCATENATE lv_html_code lv_string INTO lv_html_code.
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS demo DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS main.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS handle_sapevent
      FOR EVENT sapevent
                  OF cl_abap_browser
      IMPORTING action
                  query_table.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS demo IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA error_list TYPE cl_abap_browser=>html_table.

    SET HANDLER handle_sapevent.

    DATA: retorncode TYPE REF TO html_start.

    CREATE OBJECT retorncode.

    DATA(html_str) = retorncode->txt_html( ).

    cl_abap_browser=>show_html(
      EXPORTING
        html_string = html_str
        title       = 'Input Demo'
      IMPORTING
         html_errors = error_list ).

    IF error_list IS NOT INITIAL.
      MESSAGE 'Error in HTML' TYPE 'I' DISPLAY LIKE 'E'.
    ENDIF.
  ENDMETHOD.
  METHOD handle_sapevent.
    BREAK-POINT.
    DATA(out) = cl_demo_output_stream=>open( ).
    SET HANDLER cl_demo_output_html=>handle_output FOR out.
    out->write_data( iv_name = 'ACTION'      ia_value = action ).
    out->write_data( iv_name = 'QUERY_TABLE' ia_value = query_table ).
    out->close( ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  demo=>main( ).
```

In the ABAP call, any information sent to the URL with the prefix SAPEVENT: is redirected to the handle_sapevent method. I based myself on this code, which also works using IE;

https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenhtml_input_abexa.htm

and I used this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn" onclick="">

</body>

<script>
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function sendTOAbap(ev) {

        var oOutput = document.querySelector("div"),
            oData = {
                campo: "sucesso",
                field: "insucesso"
            };

        oData.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");

        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.open("POST", "SAPEVENT:SAPEVENT", true);
        oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
            if (oReq.status == 200) {
                console.log("Uploaded!");
            } else {
                console.log("Error " + oReq.status + " occurred when trying to upload your file.");
            }
        };

        oReq.send(oData);
        ev.preventDefault();
    }, false);
</script>

</html>
```

The problem is that when I try to run it specifically using Internet Explorer, it returns an "access denied" or "not transported" error. I cannot change the browser version as it is the SAP standard.
Tankyou to help-me.

I tried changing the access policies and changing the post methods, and changing the body.

Comment: One of the world's largest software vendors uses a deprecated/discontinued browser as their standard?!

Comment: It's not IE but an old internal Windows control. It only supports very limited features i.e. posting an HTTP request as you do won't work. Use only the same logic given by SAP (form and action). If you want to create something "sophisticated", prefer using SAPUI5 or any other Web technology. NB: since 7.70 SAP GUI supports also the Windows Chromium engine.

Comment: sap allows you to use this browser to display HTML for a function that has been discontinued, today all sap programs use UI5, however in the region where I work UI5 is not a reality it is an expensive implementation so I use this alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found outher alternative to make a post without char limits
**in a constructor make true query_disable**, ou will do dump, and

```
var prefixSendAbap = "SAPEVENT:SEND";

var form = document.createElement('form');
form.method = 'POST';
form.action = prefixSendAbap;
document.body.appendChild(form);

var formField = document.createElement('input');
formField.type = 'hidden';
formField.name = 'ContentJson';
formField.value = json;

form.appendChild(formField);

form.submit();

/* Delete Node */
document.body.removeChild(form);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i resolved the problem using this script

```
var url = 'SAPEVENT:SEE_PARAMETERS?PARAMETER=1&PARAMETER2=2&PARAMETER3=4';
document.location.href = url;
```

is simple use de sapevent like a API, using this any parameter to sap.